# How to put icon on password input form?

Tags: html, css

I have this code right here for my password input:

```
<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-md-13">
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" 
        name="password" required autocomplete="current-password" placeholder="Password">
        <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>
        @error('password')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror       
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I insert the icon to the rightmost part of the input form?
This is my current situation:

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far to achieve that ? Also do you use a `CSS` framework (like `Bootstrap`) ?

Comment: I see that you use bootstrap as css library. This can help: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/input-group/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Antonio pointed in the comments above, and because it's obvious that you're using `Bootstrap`, you may use its [`Input Group`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/input-group/) component to achieve the desired positioning of the icon.

Here's a live demo showcasing the usage of that component:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="container p-2">
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <!-- added "input-group" class -->
    <div class="col-md-13 input-group">
      <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" placeholder="Password" required>
      <!-- the eye icon now acts as the text of the input group by using "input-group-text" class -->
      <i class="input-group-text bi bi-eye-slash"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> The above demo uses `BS5` so please make the necessary changes/tweaks if you're using another `Bootstrap` version.